# How can I verify whether a function is expanded as inline by the C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, llvm, c++14, emscripten

How can I verify whether a function is expanded inline in a C++ program?
My Compiler is Emscripten but an answer for `g++` probably works.

Ideally, a code that runs differently when in inline mode (although it should not have any side effects).

Comment: You should see the generated assembly.  A `jump` statement would be missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable the `-Winline` warning which prints a warning when a function marked `inline` wasn't inlined.

See [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Inline.html).

As an alternative, you can mark the function `always_inline` which will trigger an error if it wasn't inlined. See [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes).